# Access controls in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie to Xamarin Forms.

I want to enable a `ShellSection` (tab) in my app once a specific stage has been completed.

Currently I use an `AppShell` class to handle navigation controls (currently PageOneTab is not enabled) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:MyApp="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
             FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
             Navigating="Handle_Navigating">
    <ShellItem>

        <ShellSection x:Name="HomeTab" Icon="home">
            <ShellContent>
                <MyApp:HomePage/>
            </ShellContent>
        </ShellSection>

        <ShellSection x:Name="PageOneTab" x:FieldModifier="public"  IsEnabled="False">
            <ShellContent>
                <MyApp:PageOnePage/>
            </ShellContent>
        </ShellSection>

    </ShellItem>
</Shell>
```

In the `HomePage` ContentPage I have a button click -

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

private async void HomePageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new HandlingPage());
}
```

And in my `HandlingPage` ContentPage based on the result, I want to enable the `ShellSection` `PageOneTab`.

```
public HandlingPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // do stuff....

    // then set -
    StatusTab.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

I thought by adding `x:FieldModifier="public"` to the control I would be able to access it from the `HandlingPage` however it is not available, in fact the only place I can access the control currently I believe is in the code behind of `AppShell.xaml.cs` by doing `StatusTab.IsEnabled = true;`.
I believe this may be down to `BindingContext` however not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change one ShellSection's IsEnable status, I suggest you can use **MessageCenter** to do this.

My ShellItems:

```
 <ShellItem>
    <ShellSection
        x:Name="itempage"
        Title="Browse"
        Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent>
            <local:ItemsPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </ShellSection>
    <ShellSection
        x:Name="aboutpage"
        Title="About"
        Icon="tab_about.png"
        IsEnabled="False">
        <ShellContent>
            <local:AboutPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </ShellSection>
</ShellItem>
```

And subscribe to a message in AppShell.cs:

```
 public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AppShell>(this, "Hi", (sender) =>
        {
            aboutpage.IsEnabled = true;
        });
    }
```

Sending one message in HandlingPage Contentpage:

```
 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<AppShell>(new AppShell(),"Hi");
    }
```

This is the article about **MessageCenter**, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: Stunning, this worked a treat. May I ask is using this method good design practice?